# Firebase email validation not working for hotmail?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I have an doubt, until yesterday the Firebase Plugin for authentication on Flutter was working perfectly, but today we identify that email confirmation and password recorver is just working for **gmail** email accounts.

Even when i send the password recovery email from firebase website it doesn't reach the **hotmail** account and other specific domain email accounts.

Firebase has changed something? I don't find anything about until now

Comment: Hi Frank. So, i was wondering if the problemn was on my e-mail provider. So i tested with my personal account of hotmail and my professional email. I also have tested with a test user registered on a temporaty email website. I send the email recovery directly from firebase platform. It doesn't reach any of this users. When i send the same recovery to gmail accounts it works fine. I believe hotmail (personal account) would not block any firebase email and i already checked for spam, nothing there either.

Comment: I have no doubt that the mail isn't arriving for some users, but we have no way to find out why that is. That's why I focused on explaining how Firebase works in my answer, and Firebase makes no distinction between email addresses based on the host. All outgoing verification emails go through the exact same flow. --- If you want more control over the mail delivery, you can connect it to your own existing SMTP server in the Firebase console.

Comment: I'll take a look on the documentation to understand how could i do it. Thank you very much by your answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firebase makes no distinction between email addresses based on the host. All outgoing verification emails go through the exact same flow.

So if the email doesn't reach users on a specific domain, it is because the email is being blocked on that domain's mail servers or somewhere along the way to that mail servers.

Typically this means that the messages are being flagged as spam in one of these layers. Be sure to check the spam folder of your mailbox, and if the message also isn't in there, check with your (and other upstream) administrators to see if it got caught before it reached your mailbox.

Answer (score 2):

Yes this is definitely a problem I had as well. I have solved this during the development by going to outlook settings, then select "view all outlook settings". Then go to "junk email" and there under "safe senders and domains" we have to manually add the email address of the firebase domain e.g no-reply@...

This will not take effect immediately. It takes at least 15 minutes I believe.

Answer (score 0):

Last week suddenly 74 of my business customers were not receiving any of the authentication mails, and as suggested above it turned out Microsoft was blocking reception from Google's mail relay. That is, Microsoft blocked ALL their business customers from receiving these mails. We found this by querying the MX of all the affected users, and effectively they were all outlook.com based:

```
dig mx <problemdomain>

<problem.domain>    300 IN  MX  5 <problem-domain>.mail.protection.outlook.com.
```

Microsoft support request: https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-365/firebase-authentication-emails-are-blocked-by-office-365/m-p/3750188

I think the only way out for us here is to setup our own SMTP, but when I enable that (with valid credentials) I don't get any mail at all… not even to my gmail. So far I'm pretty much stuck o_O

Answer (score 0):

April 2023,  yahoo and hotmail seem to not be receiving the verification emails.  Hotmail sometimes receives them 24 hours after being sent.  Something happening with these providers.